# Script to send emails from Database using Yii framework

Tags: php, sql, function, yii

I'm trying to create a function within the Controller so that after every successful run of the "actionCreate()" function, I want to send emails out to all members. So far this is the function that I have:

```
public function emailAll()
{
    $row = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(array(
        'select' => array('email'),
        'from' => 'tb_user',
    ))->queryRow();


    while ($row != null) {

        $to = $row['emailAdd'];
        $subject = 'NEW UPDATE FROM ADMIN';
        $message = 'HELLO TEST';
        $headers = 'From: webadmin@sample.com' . "\r\n";


        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
```

The code keeps hanging every time I run the create. Can anyone help me with the syntax for Yii in terms of using the select statement? I just want to be able to select all the email addresses.

I changed the function to this to check if even one email is even sending:

```
 $to = 'myemail@live.com';
        $subject = 'NEW UPDATE FROM ADMIN';
        $message = 'HELLO TEST';
        $headers = 'From: to@someone.com' . "\r\n";


        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: if you do like this, all users will get mail repeatedly on each new user insert. Is this your requirement?

Comment: @kumar_v: Yes that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @kumar_v: So far everytime there's an insert, the system keeps hanging.

Comment: Yes. Better you send only to new user if it's welcome email. If you want to send to all users as notification email, then you have to do with some mailing tool

Comment: @kumar_v - going a bit off the question, could recommend some good mail tools do the job without investing much

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiises/  one of yii extension for bulk email option.

Comment: @kumar_v: I was wondering if my above script is missing any code?

Comment: queryRow() will return single row only. So only one mail will send in all the case

Comment: It's not even sending one email at all. I tried many different approaches. I'm running this on a localhost.

Comment: @kumar_v: I updated my code to try sending to one email but it's not even sending still after I called the function

Comment: @charlesisjan did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid hanging, remove while loop. It's meaning less.

just use

```
$to = $row['emailAdd']; 
$subject = 'NEW UPDATE FROM ADMIN';
$message = 'HELLO TEST';
$headers = 'From: webadmin@sample.com' . "\r\n";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
 echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}
```